# "google_assistant_library-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-linux_armv71.whl" not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to install google assistant on my pi 3. follwing the instructions on the assistant sdk page i had this error:

"google_assistant_library-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-linux_armv71.whl" not a supported wheel on this platform"

on cmd: *python -m pip install --upgrade https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/releases/download/0.3.0/google_assistant_library-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-linux_armv7l.whl*

please help.

Comment: Did you update pip? `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`

Answer (score 2):

The character at the end of armv7l is a lower case L and not a number 1

Answer (score 0):

Ask your python interpreter what system architecture it is seeing.

```
$ python
>>> import platform
>>> platform.version()
'#993 SMP Wed Apr 26 18:01:23 BST 2017'
>>> platform.uname()
('Linux', 'raspberrypi', '4.9.24-v7+', '#993 SMP Wed Apr 26 18:01:23 BST 2017', 'armv7l', '')
```

Above output is from my environment which is Raspberry PI3+NOOBS+Python3.6.1. The package you are installing is for the device with ARMv7 cpu. You might able to run that script on the device with different arch with some modification. But for your kick-start, you've got to check/rebuild your environment with [official tutorials](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample), or you can try another example like [push-talk](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/) which doesn't depend on that package.